# How is coloured text stored in the clipboard?

Tags: linux, terminal, xorg, colors, clipboard

I've been using xclip to copy text to and from terminal. I was curious how it would handle coloured text from non-terminal applications such as google docs, and libreoffice

When copying from one of these document editors to another the text colour remains, however when I use `xclip -o --clipboard` there doesn't seem to be any attributes or escape codes to the copied text; only the copied text is displayed.

This makes sense for most uses, you wouldn't want random escape sequences or attributes appearing within your copied text. *Except when you do.*

I've also tried copying some red text and then directing xclip output to a .doc file which is otherwise able to support coloured text -xclip likely does not support it.

**My subsequent question is, how (if at all) can I access/view the escape sequences/colour attributes/*other-representation* associated with coloured text -in the clipboard?**

I'm aware that terminal colour to terminal colour typically uses ANSI set graphics mode escape sequences e.g. `\033[1m` for **bold**, while doc/text editors probably use a different standard.

Think this is more an X thing than terminal thing, but in case it matters I tested & found similar behaviour on xfce4-terminal & gnome-terminal.

Comment: Checked the source code? Everything should be right there, in xclip &/or your desktop

Comment: @Xen2050 looking at the [source](https://github.com/astrand/xclip/blob/6026cee00dbdda542704f5c0c5b683e9bfba6b9a/xclip.c#L439) didn't reveal anything to suggest attributes were being stripped. I'd be willing to hack at xlib to get something working, but without knowing the standards associated with the behaviour I doubt I'd achieve much.